# Diccionario con funciones no funciona

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo una funcion con un diccionario con varias funciones que insertan hacia mssql, recibo un json para validar el servicio pero envie lo que sea siempre me se ejecutan todas las funciones.

```
return switch('estado','i','{"Code": "10", "Description": "Industrial", "Source": "0", "Transfer_status": "1"}')

def switch(case,action,data):
    sw = {
        'producto': producto(action,data),
        'precio': precio(action,data),
        'canalDistrb': canalDistrb(action,data),
        'sector': sector(action,data),
        'gpocliente': gpocliente(action,data),
        'familias': familia(action,data),
        'estado': estado(action,data)
    }
    return sw.get(case,default(case))

def default(case):
   return {"Servicio Invalido": case}

def producto(action,data):
    print('producto')
```

y en consola me muestra todos los procedimientos por el momento para pruebas solo puse un print.

pero se ejecutan todos.

```
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 220-831-626
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
producto
precio
canal
sector
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2021 02:01:13] "POST /data HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Si publicas un código que sea copiar-y-pegar para poderlo probar, podremos analizarlo. Falta un ejemplo completo y claro para analizar el problema. Se ve interesante; sería una lástima cerrarlo por incompleto.

Comment: según entiendo, al declarar `sw`, estás llamando a todas las funciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He simplificado tu código, ya que faltan partes de ello. No puedo ayudarte con exactitud a tu petición, pero si he simulado solo el supuesto de que solo hay una función y es `estado`. Puedes añadir tus funciones.

Ten en cuenta que ese codigo es puramente para estudio, en según que contexto cambiaría mucho. Es funcional para lo que pides.

#### solución

```
def estado(action, data):
    print(f'Se ejecuta la funcion estado con '
          f'\naction: {action} '
          f'\ndata: {data}')


def switch(case, action, data):
    return globals()[case](action, data)


switch('estado', 'i', '{"Code": "10", "Description": "Industrial", "Source": "0", "Transfer_status": "1"}')
```

Mi output generado es ese:

```
runfile('/home/gil/PycharmProjects/testing/test.py', wdir='/home/gil/PycharmProjects/testing')
Se ejecuta la funcion estado con 
action: i 
data: {"Code": "10", "Description": "Industrial", "Source": "0", "Transfer_status": "1"}
```

#### problema en tu código

Al definir un diccionario se ejecutan todos los estamentos dentro de el. Todo lo que lleva un `()` va a ser ejecutado y va formar parte de él.

No merece la pena duplicar código, no hace falta un diccionario para eso.

Siempre que quieras llamar a atributos de variables ( o sea también funciones) deberás utilizar  `locales`,`globales`, o el método `getattrib`.

En este caso he escogido globales para ponértelo fácil

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en tu diccionario:

```
    sw = {
        'producto': producto(action,data),
        'precio': precio(action,data),
        'canalDistrb': canalDistrb(action,data),
        'sector': sector(action,data),
        'gpocliente': gpocliente(action,data),
        'familias': familia(action,data),
        'estado': estado(action,data)
    }
```

lo que estás almacenando no es qué función debe ejecutarse para cada clave, sino **el resultado** de haber ejecutado cada una de esas funciones, pues estás invocando las funciones al usar paréntesis tras su nombre.

Lo que querrías es simplemente asociar a cada clave qué función le corresponde, pero sin invocarla. La solución podría ser por tanto así:

```
def switch(case,action,data):
    sw = {
        'producto': producto,
        'precio': precio,
        'canalDistrb': canalDistrb,
        'sector': sector,
        'gpocliente': gpocliente,
        'familias': familias,
        'estado': estado
    }
    funcion = sw.get(case)
    if funcion:
      return funcion(action, data)
    else:
      return default(case)
```

Fíjate como en este caso el diccionario simplemente almacena para cada clave cuál es el nombre de la función a invocar. Esa función se extrae con `sw.get(case)`  (y si la clave no existe este `.get()` retornará `None`). Seguidamente, se invoca a la función extraida pasándole los parámetros (`funcion(action, data)`) o bien a la función `default()` si el valor extraido es `None`.

### Nota

En este caso además se tiene que el nombre de las funciones a invocar coincide con la cadena usada como clave (es decir, ante la clave `"producto"` se ejecuta la función llamada `producto`). Esto podría simplificar el código, pero sacrificando bastante la legibilidad, haciendo uso del diccionario `globals()` en el que están todos los símbolos definidos en el código (y por tanto las funciones `producto()`, `precio()`, etc.) Gracias a esto no necesitarías el diccionario `sw` sino que puedes directamente extraer del diccionario `globals()` la función requerida:

```
def switch(case,action,data):
    funcion = globals().get(case)
    if funcion:
      return funcion(action, data)
    else:
      return default(case)
```

Sin embargo encuentro más legible y flexible el enfoque con el diccionario `sw`, pues te permite independizar las cadenas usadas en las claves de los nombres de las funciones que implementan la funcionalidad necesaria. Además el caso `globals()` es más "peligroso" pues proporcionando a `switch()` la clave adecuada, se podría ejecutar cualquier otra función definida en tu módulo. Y por último, si la clave que se le pasa resulta ser el nombre de una variable en vez de una función, ésta sería también encontrda en el diccionario `globals()` y después la línea que intenta invocarla como `funcion()` fallaría (por no tratarse de una función invocable).