# Se puede tener un diccionario de funciones?

Tags: python

tengo  una   diccionario  con grupo de funciones, pero cuando  accedo al diccionario, y  obtengo  la función ...  y con esa   función  deseo trabajar no me   funciona...  no se cómo resolver o que estoy haciendo mal  Muchas gracias !!

```
def ab(amount):
    calculate_tax = 22
    return calculate_tax*amount
def bc(amount):
    calculate_tax = 33
    return calculate_tax*amount
def cd(amount):
    calculate_tax = 434
    return calculate_tax*amount

tax_list = {
    "a": ab,
    "b": bc,
    "c": cd
    }

def calculate_tax(country_name, amount):
    #  en este punto   obtengo la función para proceder a multiplicar... pero no funciona   
    x = tax_list[country_name]
    return x(amount)

print(calculate_tax("a", 2))
```

Comment: Tu código es correcto. ¿En qué sentido dices que no funciona? He probado a ejecutarlo y sale 44, que es la respuesta esperable (2*22)

Comment: El código está perfecto. No veo ningún problema.

Comment: Me acuerdo haber leído una respuesta de alguno de ustedes dos (@abulafia, @CandidMoe) en cuanto a eso, yo creo que es duplicada, eliminaré el comentario si la encuentro

Comment: @HeytalePazguato tal vez te refieras a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/430686/7123) pero no la veo pertinente aquí ya que de hecho en este caso el código de salinashf es correcto y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @abulafia, sí era esa. Si, el código funciona correctamente pero yo creo que de haber visto esa pregunta y su respuesta antes de publicarla tal vez no se hubiera realizado. Solo era como referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que tal vez sea más sencillo de esta forma:

```
tax_list = {
    "a": 22,
    "b": 33,
    "c": 434
}

def calculate_tax( country_name, amount ):
    return calcula( amount, tax_list[ country_name ] )

print( calculate_tax( "a", 2 ))
```

En vez de usar tres funciones que básicamente hacen lo mismo (multiplicar dos números), simplifico el código, haciendo que **tax_list** me devuelva uno de los números a multiplicar, y luego procedo con la multiplicación.
Ahora si lo que hacías era una prueba de concepto sobre cono asignar funciones a variables... mi respuesta es un sin sentido total.

Comment: Usa funciones, como lo pide el OP, es más general. Cada función puede hacer el cálculo de manera diferente, sin afectar al resto de los cálculos.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.